# Rails How To Manually Create Child Object Without Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I was wondering what the best implementation would be to programatically generate a single child object for a parent(s) without the use of a form.

In my case I have an existing forum system that I would like to tie into my Upload system via comments. I would like to manually create a child Forum object to discuss said upload in the same create action that the Upload is created. The two models have a relationship as so:

Child forum:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   belongs_to :upload
end
```

Parent upload:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_one :forum
end
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    #Create the upload and a new forum + initial post to discuss the upload
    @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])
    @forum = Forum.new(:upload_id => @upload.id, :title => @upload.name...)
    @first_post = Post.new(:forum_id => @forum.id....)    
    if @upload.save && @topic.save && @first_post.save
      redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @upload.id
    else
      redirect_to :action => "new"
    end 
  end

end
```

Which is fairly close to what I wanted to do but the parent ids aren't generated until the parent objects are saved. I could probably do something like:

```
@upload.save 
@forum = Forum.new(:upload_id => @upload.id...
@forum.save....
```

But I thought it might be cleaner to only persist the objects if they all validated. I'm not sure, does anybody else know of a better implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend moving the forum creation from the controller to the model. The forum will only be created on the successful creation of the Upload.

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :forum
  after_create :create_forum
  ...
  def create_forum
    Forum.create(:upload_id => self.id, :title => self.name...)
  end
end


class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :posts
  after_create :create_first_post
  ...
  def create_first_post
    Post.new(:forum_id => self.id)
    # or self.posts << Post.new()
  end
end
```

Comment: That seems like a much better solution, I'm assuming I would just create the initial Post in the same method following the Forum creation?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, the Forum never gets created and fails silently.

Comment: create fails silently because the validations are not being meet. Make sure that all the values are populated and pass.  For debugging purposes, change create to the bang method create! to cause Rails to reveal the issue.

Comment: I updated my example to include the Post creation in the Forum object.

Comment: You were right, there was some fields that were getting set to nil because they weren't set as accessible. I might have to create the Post record in the same method because it's going to contain contents from the Upload record and that will conflict with when a user creates a new Forum normally without an Upload.